# Get only 1 document from 'data' collection of the user by UID using ReactJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore

I have several documents in the 'data' collection and every document in the 'data' collection is related to a user from the 'users' collection.
document id from 'users' collection is equal to document id from 'data' collection.

I'm trying to get the data from the 'data' collection by UID of the user from Firestore, but it gets all the documents from the 'data' collection.

How can I get only a single document from the 'data' collection by the UID of the user when the user is signed in?

Firestore screenshot:

[image: Firestore]

the document above is related to a user from the 'users' collection and has the same ID.

code:

```
export default function Nutrition() {

const [data, setData] = useState([]);

useEffect(() => {
    const dbRef = collection(db, "data");
    onAuthStateChanged(auth, async (user) => {
        if (user) {
            const uid = user.uid;
            const snapshot = await getDoc(doc(db, "data", uid));
            if (snapshot.exists()) {
                onSnapshot(dbRef, (querySnapshot) => {
                    let foods = [];
                    querySnapshot.forEach(doc => {
                        const { value, quantity } = doc.data()
                        for (let i = 0; i < value.length; i++) {
                            foods.push({ value: value[i], quantity: quantity[i] })
                        }
                    });
                    setData(foods)
                })
            } else {
                console.log("User doc missing")
            }
        } else {
            console.log("User not logged in")
        }
    })
})

return (
    <React.Fragment>
        {true ? (
            <div className='container mt-3'>
                {/* table */}
                <table className='table table-hover'>
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th>#</th>
                            <th>Food</th>
                            <th>Quantity</th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>

                    <tbody>
                        {data.map((row, index) => {
                            return (
                                <tr key={data.id}>
                                    <td>{index + 1}</td>
                                    <td>{row.value}</td>
                                    <td>{row.quantity}</td>
                                </tr>
                            )
                        })}
                    </tbody>
                </table>
            </div>) : <p>data error</p>}
    </React.Fragment>
)
```

}

Answer (score 0):

You're attaching the `onSnapshot` to `dbRef`, which is initialized as:

```
const dbRef = collection(db, "data");
...
onSnapshot(dbRef, (querySnapshot) => {
```

To listen only to the user's data, do:

```
onSnapshot(doc(dbRef, uid), (querySnapshot) => {
```